# Block-matrix: optimal fill-in reduction for LU factorization

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization, block-decomposition

Consider a square $N \times N$ block-matrix $\mathbf{A}$, where each $n \times n$ block $\mathbf{A}_{ii}$ is either a dense block or a zero-block. So, $N$ denotes the number of blocks, $n$ denotes the size of each square block.

Random example for illustration:
$$
\mathbf{A}=\left[ 
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\mathbf{A}_{11} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_{13} & \mathbf{A}_{14} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{A}_{21} & \mathbf{A}_{22} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_{25} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_{33} & \mathbf{A}_{34} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_{43} & \mathbf{A}_{44} & \mathbf{0} \\
\mathbf{A}_{51} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{A}_{55} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

**Now, one wants to compute an LU decomposition of this block matrix with minimal fill-in.**

I am generally aware of the algorithms for reducing the fill-in for general sparse matrices. Say, [Matlab reference](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/sparse-matrix-reordering.html) gives an overview of several methods and their effect on Cholesky factorization. However, these algorithms certainly do not give **an optimal reordering** to give an optimal structure for the factorization in preserving zeros. This is done for a very good reason: for a large sparse matrix, finding an optimal reordering is very expensive, unneeded, and is unlikely to give substantial benefits compared to the common relatively fast techniques.

However, I wonder if that can be slightly different for the factorization of a block-matrix. In this case, $N$ is an order of magnitudes smaller, and one might be willing to use very expensive [graph?] algorithms to find this optimal fill-in for a given block pattern.

I wonder:

- what family of algorithms should I look at?
- is there a canonical reference on this aspect of reducing fill-in? (my search is constantly swamped by results on reducing fill-in of simple sparse matrices not the block-wise case with its own peculiarities – as much more expensive algorithm can become feasible)?
- is it even a tangible problem for relatively small $N$?

Notes:

- In this example, all blocks have the same $n \times n$ size for simplicity, and I am interested in it. I might be interested in the example where each block is still square, but the block-sizes differ.
- For my applications, the number of blocks $N$ can range from 1 (trivial) to, say, 100, and $n$ is on the order of thousands (not that $n$ matters at all).
- I am willing to spend significant precomputation time (say 10$\times t_\text{LU}$) to analyze the pattern and come up with the best reordering

Comment: You say: "reducing fill-in of simple sparse matrices not the block-wise case with its own peculiarities". It seems to me that as far as determining a fill-reducing ordering, it is irrelevant whether the block size is 100x100 or 1x1 (e.g. scalar).  Why do you see the problem differently?

Comment: @BillGreene you are totally right. $n$, block-size is totally irrelevant (especially when all blocks have the same size $n \times n$)

Comment: I wanted to highlight that $n$ is usually in the order of tens of thousands when the reordering algorithms for reducing fill in are applied (and $N=1$). I am interested in the case when $N$ (num blocks, the dimension that matters) is relatively small, but larger than 1 -> block matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, optimal reordering is NP-complete, so all the algorithms in this space are kinda heuristic. At first glance my instinct would be to try some variant of minimum degree, mainly because the bisection-based algorithms (nested-dissection / recursive-spectral-bisection) would seem not really applicable.. their heuristics are kinda rooted in the geometry/sparse connectivity of a 2D/3D mesh.

The particular example is interesting in that the pattern is not symmetric, and most of the reordering codes in wide use are meant for symmetric matrices or nearly-symmetric perturbations. I think [KLU is a noteworthy exception](https://doi.org/10.1145/1824801.1824814), a sparse solver that is not so tailored for symmetry/FEM (it's for circuits). Perhaps take a look at how it reorders matrices?

For extremely small numbers of blocks (less than 7 or so?) there's always the possibility of trying every permutation, performing symbolic factorization on the pattern, then just picking the best? I don't think I would recommend this since it won't scale, but if you have known upper bounds on N, it could be an easy thing to try.

Comment: that's a very interesting algorithm I was not aware of, and [this documentation](https://fossies.org/linux/SuiteSparse/KLU/Doc/palamadai_e.pdf) is a very interesting read on every level!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will be helpful to you (since it is a late answer and you already accepted the other answer) but there is a decent literature review of bandwidth minimizing algorithms in https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01166658/document .

I would think the matrix as a graph and collapse each block into a single node, i.e. if two nodes of the directed graph -corresponding to the non-symmetric sparse matrix- are connected via a bidirected edge then collapse them. That would end up reducing the graph size significantly enough that most bandwidth minimizing algorithms would be feasible. I probably would use Reverse Cuthill-McKee ( MATLAB implementation https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/symrcm.html ) but that is mostly due to its availability.

Comment: Thanks for the overview, I haven't seen this one. However, these types of algorithms do not provide optimal reordering. Which is certainly a good decision for a large sparse matrix, but maybe not for a block-matrix question, where more expensive and less scalable algorithms can be used.

Comment: They cite Caprara  A.  and  J.  J.  Salazar,  2005 as an optimal labeling algorithm for medium size graphs. I don't know if there is a public implementation of their 'branch and bound' method.